# How can I list files with a certain extension only in a directory to a txt file with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with about 100 files.  Is there a way that I can list the contents of a directory to a txt file using powershell?

```
My directory is C:\logs\weekly
```

What I would like is for the files with ONLY the .log extension to be listed like this:

```
weekly\file1.log
weekly\file2.log
weekly\file3.log
```

Comment: Is there _anything_ you have tried. This is a fairly trivial thing to do with PowerShell. `Get-ChildItem` and `Set-Content` would be examples to use. The only thing here that is _slightly_ different is you are removing some of the path... there are questions here on that as well.... Have to find a couple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log | Select FullName -ExpandProperty FullName | Set-Content YourFileName.txt
```

And if you don't want the full path then just use a regex replace like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log | % {
    % {$_.FullName  -replace '^.*\\([^\\]+\\.*)$', '$1'}
} | Set-Content YourFileName.txt
```

Comment: Your answer works good but every row still includes C:\logs  Is there a way I can get it to exclude that as in the question.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Amended my answer to only save file name and folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straight-forward.

Use `Get-ChildItem` to get the child items, and then call `Substring()` on the `FullName` (the path) property, using the `Length` of the parent path to determine where to cut it:

```
function Get-ChildItemWithoutParent {
    param(
        [string]$Path,
        [string]$Filter,
        [switch]$Recurse
    )

    $ParentPathLength = (Split-Path $Path -Parent).Length + 1

    Get-ChildItem @PSBoundParameters |ForEach-Object {
        $_.FullName.Substring($ParentPathLength)
    }
}
```

Using the [`$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx), we can *re-use* (or *proxy*) parameters to the inner cmdlet call without doing all sorts of custom handling, pretty neat

Now you just need to pipe the output to a file:

```
Get-ChildItemWithoutParent -Path 'C:\logs\weekly' -Filter *.log | Out-File -Path .\textfile.txt
```